Nodejs mongodb insert with `_id`, but `_id` becomes empty object
I'm inserting some records with _id = new ObjectId('a string with 24 length') to a collection in mongo with nodejs.
But the result _id in mongo becomes an empty object: {}, resulting in failure in subsequent insertions. (empty object are always equal).
This is what I got in console.log (argument of collection.insertMany):
[
  {
    _id: { [Symbol(id)]: <Buffer 66 c2 a5 85 44 85 81 17 a7 10 9e 25> },
    entity_unique_id: '123'
  },
  {
    _id: { [Symbol(id)]: <Buffer 66 c2 a5 85 44 85 81 17 a7 10 9e 20> },
    entity_unique_id: '456'
  }
]

This is the insertion result in mongo (only 1 record because the 2nd failed due to duplicate _id):
{
    "_id" : {

    },
    "entity_unique_id" : "123"
}

npm mongodb driver version: 4.11.0
mongo version: 3.6.23 (docker-compose)

1st of all don't share image ,share code in text format. Regarding the issue Share how you are performing insertion opeartion and how did you define the Schema. Edit your question & share these two details.

btw, mongodb 3.6 died 3 years ago https://www.mongodb.com/legal/support-policy/lifecycles. It's been a lovely version, but it's time to let it go and move on.

You can check if the _id  value you are creating for insertion is a valid value or not in your application, using the static method ObjectId.isValid(your_object_id), before each insert operation.

@prasad_ I've checked, and it returns true.

Can you tell what this string value  you are working with: 'a string with 24 length'?

It's actually just the _id string created by mongo. I'm fetching data from prod, then insert them in my local mongo. The value is 66c2a58544858117a7109e25
